# What does “Trump opposes women who were born women” really mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

New Yorker April 22 issue carried Andy Borowitz’s article that came under the title,
“Trump reassures supporters that he still opposes women who were born women.”
It begins with the following passage:

> “After rattling many of his supporters by expressing tolerance toward
>   transgender people, the Republican front-runner Donald J. Trump
>   clarified on Friday that he still opposes women who were born women.
>   “The media has tried to blow my words out of proportion,” Trump said
>   on the Fox News Channel. “Just because I happen to think transgender
>   people deserve our understanding in no way means that I feel that way
>   about women who were born women.”
>   http://www.newyorker.com/humor/borowitz-report/trump-reassures-supporters-that-he-still-opposes-women-who-were-born-women?

What does “women who were born women” mean? Doesn’t it mean “women in general, which represents a half all of electoral votes”?
If so, why does he “still oppose women who were born women, and turning women into his enemy? Doesn’t this massage contradict with his subsequent remark?

> Trump said that any attempt to twist his words to apply to “women in
>   general” was deeply offensive to him. “I have made my views about
>   women very clear and to suggest that I have somehow changed those
>   views is really, really hurtful,” he said.

Isn’t some words, like “who suspect” missing from the headline, “Trump reassures supporters that he still opposes women who were born women.”?

Comment: It looks to me like Mr Trump either was slightly misquoted or he got his phrases kind of out of order.  And the person writing the headlines is taking advantage of that to further twist the appearance of Mr Trump's (already rather oddly contorted) views.

Comment: Don't try to make sense of Trump's words, here or elsewhere. And yes, contradictions and inconsistencies abound. That's part of appearing to be anything to anyone.

Comment: To re-enforce what surlawda says below, following above link (which wasn't there in the original) reveals that the article is a satire piece, not to be taken seriously.

Comment: *The Borowitz Report* is a satirical news column. Borowitz makes things up. He's a comedian, and makes the most outlandish and false statements with great effect in his columns. What he's saying essentially is that Trump still hates women.

Comment: @medica. What I can't still understand is how it can be possible to be the top runner of GOP Presidential candidates by proclaiming that he hates women in public, in other word, saying a 50 percent of all electorates are his enemies . Even if it's a commedian's satire, that doesn't follow the logic, nor makes sense.

Comment: Trump didn't actually ever say that. Andy Borowitz put those words into his mouth, so to speak. He did so for a number of reasons, mainly choosing to make fun of him that way because of his transgender turnaround. Borowitz is saying Trump's turnaround *shouldn't alarm anyone; he "still hates women"* (he's still a hateful person, just like before.) Though Trump never said that *exactly*, it's the things he does say (he denigrates women) and the way he acts.

Comment: @YoichiOishi As medica says, Trump did not say what he is quoted as saying in this article. It is a joke, a spoof, a parody--it is fiction, made up, pretend.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Your confusion is understandable, The fact is, Trump has actually said many things that are extremely insulting to women, just as he has insulted Mexicans and Muslims, which is not normal--politicians typically do not insult large blocs of voters. So many people are confused, because often, when Trump insults these groups, he becomes more popular. You're right--this does not follow logic, or make sense, except that the US electorate is currently in a hostile mood, and they like the hostility they see in Trump. Again, this specific quote, "oppose women who were born women," ...

Comment: ... this a false quote. It is intended to be funny. But for something to be funny, it is often said, there must be an element of truth in it. The element of truth here is that this quote does conform with Trump's hostility toward women. He didn't actually say it, but people can easily imagine his saying it, because he really does say very insulting things. And, like you, we are all confused.

Comment: The problem is there is too much truth to it.  It fails as a joke simply because it wouldn't surprise anyone if he actually said it. It'd be like hanging a door so it swings the other way.  It's only funny when you expect the door to only swing one way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is satire. The writer is making fun of Trump after Trump came out with a statement supporting transgender rights. Trump is widely viewed as a sexist pig who instinctually objectifies women--he is someone who is said to hate women, because he sees them as for his own sexual gratification and nothing else. This appeals to his right-wing supporters. So, now, he says something intelligent about leaving transgender people alone, and the right wing is throwing a fit. This article is a joke suggesting that Trump is trying to placate the right wing by assuring them that he still hates women who were born women (i.e., who are not transgender.)

Comment: Good answer but how is this a question about the English language? This question should be closed.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride this is a question about parsing language and context vs sound bite.  Sure it's politically charged but we can take it.

Comment: Putting aside whatever opinions I may have about the matter: this answer reads more like a diatribe than an analysis of what the statement in the OP means. "sexist pig...who hate[s] women" "this appeals to his right-wing supporters" Really?

Comment: That's the mindset the writing in question is coming from, so that context is important to understand the language here.

Comment: "Trump is widely viewed" =/= "Trump is here portrayed" (If it matters--I would never vote for Trump)

Comment: @brianpck I suppose the answer could have been worded more objectively, but I think it is a reasonably good summary of the way in which the Borowitz piece was intended to be understood and the context within which that understanding was to occur.

Answer (score -2):

(Mostly) fictitious insult-humor faux-news skit, based on comic premise of a candidate being more tolerant of a minority than most of his supporters are -- therefore, said candidate comically compensates, by emphasizing the wide traditional prejudices he and his supporters still share.

As comedy goes, it's a bit smarmy, as it indirectly flatters the *New Yorker* reader for being morally superior to *that* candidate's supporters, and also for the reader's being clever enough to see the author's joke.   "Preaching to the choir."

Comment: That's "choir". I doubt anyone would attempt to give a sermon to a few sheets of paper; they are not known to be good listeners. Actually this answer would be much better without the second paragraph, which may be a legitimate criticism but has little to do with the question of how to parse the meaning of the article.

Comment: @DavidK: While I agree that the idiom is composed using the word "choir", the word "quire" as well as meaning paper also (and IMO more commonly) refers to the architectural part of a church in which the choir resides, between the nave and the sanctuary. There are certainly interpretations of "preaching to the quire" that could be deemed valid and logical, when you consider similar phrases like "announcing to the room".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought the architectural feature also was called a "choir". Upon looking a little further down the page on the "dictionary" sites, however, I noticed that "quire" is also listed as an archaic variant (or obsolete spelling) of "choir". So "preaching to the quire" isn't _wrong,_ after all, merely (in my opinion) excessively quaint.

Comment: @DavidK: "Quire" is still very much the commonly-used word in that context, at least in the Anglican church. Your dictionary's "archaic/obsolete" notation may be US-specific; I don't know. I do notice now that the Wikipedia entry on the topic appears to have been similarly US-washed, even when giving cathedrals in the UK as examples. Shocking!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Obsolete" was from the "British dictionary definitions" section of http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quire, but who knows which "Britsh" dictionary that would be; so I looked in the Compact Edition of the OED, which noted that the English Book of Common Prayer still (in 1971) used the spelling _quire_ and that the word is "fictitiously" spelled _choir_ but pronounced _quire_; but all of this is listed in the entry for _choir_ (alphabetized under C). I suppose if you want to communicate with British Anglicans, _quire_ will do fine; for anyone else, I recommend _choir._

Comment: @DavidK: "fictitiously" haha nice :)

Comment: @DavidK, the skill level of satirical marksmanship, the difficulty of the object aimed for, and how close to the mark it hit, especially when seen (as by the OP) from a remoter cultural distance, (where such rankings are not easily inferred), are relevant to the _meaning_ of a humor piece.

Comment: Is there a culture in which political satire never flatters the people who agree with the satirist? I suppose OP is an adult and intelligent enough to perceive how this kind of satire would be received, given just a few signposts to indicate the nature of the satire. Anyway, there must be at least two people other than me who felt some part of this answer would better have been omitted, because I did not give any of the downvotes.

Comment: Political or otherwise, _good_ satire never flatters, (non-ironically anyway); the _style_ of satire may vary among cultures, but not it's _nature_.